# Excel - Sum highest n values in horizontal cells which aren't beside each other

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a spread sheet to calculate golf scores and handicaps. There is 8 games. Player of the year is calculated on a players top 5 scores. I need a formula which will sum the top 5 values of a players points. The players points are in the blue columns and the best 5 total points are  stored in the yellow AR column.

[image]

Now, I am not an Excel expert but here is my attempt at a solution.

The problem is that I have to create a custom range for every player (which is not cool):

```
=Sheet1!$E$2,Sheet1!$J$2,Sheet1!$O$2,Sheet1!$T$2,Sheet1!$Y$2,Sheet1!$AD$2,Sheet1!$AI$2,Sheet1!$AN$2
```

And then I have to create a unique formula for each individual player (which is also not cool):

```
=LARGE(Bergin_Martin,1)+ LARGE(Bergin_Martin,2)+ LARGE(Bergin_Martin,3)+ LARGE(Bergin_Martin,4)+ LARGE(Bergin_Martin,5)
```

This works ok but it's not ideal if I want to add new players. Does anyone know of a formula which I can use without the need to create 1) a unique range for each player and 2) a unique formula to sum up the unique ranges?

Comment: Does this work? `=LARGE((E2,J2,O2,T2,Y2,AD2,AI2,AN2),1) + ...` (obviously fill in the `...` with each `LARGE`

Comment: Nice one @ChrisHaas that worked a treat :)

Comment: Shortened version: `=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((E2,J2,O2,T2,Y2,AD2,AI2,AN2),{1,2,3,4,5}))`

Comment: @tigeravatar, I always forget about array formulas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(comment converted to answer)*

When an Excel Parameter takes an `Array` you can pass in a dynamically generated one by wrapping the columns in parenthesis and separating each with commas. This allows you to use the slightly shorter but draggable:

```
=LARGE((E2,J2,O2,T2,Y2,AD2,AI2,AN2),1) + LARGE((E2,J2,O2,T2,Y2,AD2,AI2,AN2),2) + LARGE((E2,J2,O2,T2,Y2,AD2,AI2,AN2),3) + LARGE((E2,J2,O2,T2,Y2,AD2,AI2,AN2),4) + LARGE((E2,J2,O2,T2,Y2,AD2,AI2,AN2),5)
```

And then as @tigeravatar pointed out, you can use an [Array Formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx) for the second parameter of `LARGE` that `SUMPRODUCT` will apply through and calculate giving you the much shorter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((E2,J2,O2,T2,Y2,AD2,AI2,AN2),{1,2,3,4,5}))
```